# How to fix React:' variable' is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs

I have just started learnig react i am stuck on this problem i have created an array expenses. There is no problem with declaration but it is throwing error while using it.

```
import ExpenseItem from "./components/ExpenseItem";
function App() {
const expenses = [
{
  id: "e1",
  title: "Toilet Paper",
  amount: 94.12,
  date: new Date(2020, 7, 14),
},
{ 
  id: "e2", 
  title: "New TV", 
  amount: 799.49,
  date: new Date(2021, 2, 12) 
 },

]; return (
<div>
  <h2>Let's get started!</h2>
  <ExpenseItem
    title={expenses[0].title}
    amount={expense[0].amount}
    date={expense[0].date}
  ></ExpenseItem>
  <ExpenseItem
    title={expenses[1].title}
    amount={expense[1].amount}
    date={expense[1].date}
  ></ExpenseItem>
</div>
    );
     }
   export default App;
```

And the error log is :

```
 src\App.js
 Line 23:17:  'expense' is not defined  no-undef
 Line 24:15:  'expense' is not defined  no-undef
 Line 28:17:  'expense' is not defined  no-undef
 Line 29:15:  'expense' is not defined  no-undef
```

Comment: you have 4 typos

Comment: Typos, `expense` isn't the same as `expenses`.

Comment: yeah my bad thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you misspelled `expenses` and instead wrote `expense` in your `ExpenseItem` element. Fixing the typo should fix your code.

Comment: yeah its fixed.

Answer (score 0):

function app should have returned:

```
return (
<div>
  <h2>Let's get started!</h2>
  <ExpenseItem
    title={expenses[0].title}
    amount={expenses[0].amount}
    date={expenses[0].date}
  ></ExpenseItem>
  <ExpenseItem
    title={expenses[1].title}
    amount={expenses[1].amount}sa
    date={expenses[1].date}
  ></ExpenseItem>
</div>
);
```